# What's the easiest way to add a zero-byte to a byte array?

Tags: c#

I'm converting a `byte[]` to a `BigInteger` and I want to ensure it comes out positive. [The docs say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207.aspx):

> To prevent positive values from being misinterpreted as negative values, you can add a zero-byte value to the end of the array.

But it doesn't specify how. So, how can I do this?

---

Found this to be the simplest:

```
public static BigInteger UnsignedBigInt(byte[] bytes)
{
    if ((bytes[bytes.Length - 1] & 0x80) != 0) Array.Resize(ref bytes, bytes.Length + 1);
    return new BigInteger(bytes);
}
```

[Thanks dtb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292424/65387)

Comment: What does the array come from?

Comment: @SLaks: `Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()`

Comment: That is unlikely to be a good idea.  You probably want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Comment: @SLaks: You sure? I only care about uniqueness, not difficulty of guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = ...

if ((bytes[bytes.Length - 1] & 0x80) != 0)
{
    Array.Resize<byte>(ref bytes, bytes.Length + 1);
}

BigInteger result = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use static method System.Array.Resize. In your case:

```
byte[] b = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
System.Array.Resize<byte>(ref b, b.Length + 1);
b[b.Length - 1] = 0;
```

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to assign the last 0 byte because that's the default value create by `Resize`.

Comment: @Gabe: It is not specified in the help for Array.Resize.

Comment: The help says "If newSize is greater than the Length of the old array, a new array is allocated and all the elements are copied from the old array to the new one." When the new array is created, all elements start out with the value `default(T)`. Since it doesn't specify what happens to the elements beyond *oldSize*, they are left with `default(T)`, which happens to be 0 for `byte`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dest = new byte[17];
Array.Copy(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), dest , 16);
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(dest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is explained at the bottom of the page. Please have a look at the sample:

```
ulong originalNumber = UInt64.MaxValue;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(originalNumber);
if (originalNumber > 0 && (bytes[bytes.Length - 1] & 0x80) > 0) 
{
   byte[] temp = new byte[bytes.Length];
   Array.Copy(bytes, temp, bytes.Length);
   bytes = new byte[temp.Length + 1];
   Array.Copy(temp, bytes, temp.Length);
}

BigInteger newNumber = new BigInteger(bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Converted the UInt64 value {0:N0} to {1:N0}.", 
                  originalNumber, newNumber);
```

Please note that this code is copied from MSDN site, as to show how to deal with big numbers that may be treated as negative numbers during conversion to BigInt. When it comes to efficiency this is *not* the best what you can get, and there are far better snippets provided in this thread.

Comment: I guess I didn't scroll down quite far enough; still I was hoping for a 1-liner.

Comment: @Mark: The quality of your code is in no way related to the number of lines required.  "Hoping for a one-liner" is a waste of time.

Comment: @EdS. No, it isn't, but then I have to extract this away into a method to keep it clean, and then I have to decide if I want to create a new static class for working with binary data, and so forth, when I just needed one little thing. Then your whole project becomes cluttered with little helper methods... wrong or right, sometimes I like to keep things tight.

Comment: @Mark: Doesn't sound like an actual problem to me.  Stick it in a static class, somewhere else, whatever; it will work, it won't be a problem in practice, and you can move past this to continue solving real problems.

Comment: @EdS.: True, the quality of the code is not directly related to number of lines. But in this case, the code is ridiculously bad (copying the array twice) rather than simply calling `Array.Resize`. It really *is* a one-liner.

Comment: @Gabe: Yeah, I wasn't defending this code snippet so much as arguing that accomplishing something in one line of code is never a valid or useful requirement.

Comment: @EdS.: Given all other things equal (memory + performance), I'll always take the shorter code. It's also easier to read and maintain. Is that better reasoning?

Comment: @Mark: Performance and lines of code have absolutely no measurable relationship.  That said... I didn't really mean to start a debate :).  I just don't think I would spend much time trying to find shorter, a alternate solution to one that already works.

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty darn simple:

```
var bytesAfter = bytesBefore.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I saw the concat method, but didn't like converting to an enumerable and back :)

Comment: Why not? It only took 25 milliseconds to append a `0` to a million byte array in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
var x = BigInteger.Abs(new BigInteger(bytes));
```

Comment: I thought about that, but now you're creating possible collisions. (i.e., same number for two different byte arrays)

Comment: But you said you always wanted it to be positive.  So assuming a 1 byte array both 0x00 and 0x80 are treated as zero.

Comment: This won't work. It interprets the number as twos complement if the high order bit is set. So doing this will interpret (for example) 

BigInteger.Abs(new BigInteger(new byte[]{255}) as 1 since BigInteger will return -1. Presumably the OP wants 255 to be 255 not 1. :)

Comment: Also note that BigInteger(byte[]) expects the array should be in little-endian order, from lowest-order byte to highest-order byte.  And Guid.ToByteArray() does not state the byte order!

Comment: @RichardSchneider: I don't actually care about the number, just uniqueness.

Comment: Hmm...if you just care about uniqueness than why do you care if the number is positive or not?

Comment: @aquinas: Because if I just take the absolute value, then both the binary representations for "1" and "-1" will map to "1", i.e., it won't give me a unique 1:1 mapping.

Comment: No, I'm not saying take the absolute value, I'm saying, if you just care about UNIQUE values, well, -1 and 1 are unique...

Comment: @aquinas: Ohhh...I see what you mean. That would be fine, except that it causes problems with what I do with the number next :) I'm running it through another function after this that only accepts non-negative values.